# How to find the distance to boundaries using an existing and refined medial axis?

Tags: python, image-processing, thickness, medial-axis

**Problem**: I have ring-like binary images with varying thicknesses. I want to calculate its thickness at n places of that ring-like segment.

**My approach**: Find the medial axis and distance transform. The distance transform maximizes at the medial axis, so I can use those distances and explain the thicknesses as distance*2.

**Challenge**: Since the images are a bit complex, when I use [skimage.morphology.medial_axis](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#medial-axis) to calculate the medial axis and distance transform, the medial axis branches at some points, which I do not want. I want a single ring-like medial axis without any branching. This messes up the distance transform results as well.

[image: Medial axis]

**What I tried**: I used NetworkX and refined the medial axis.
[image: Refined medial axis]

**Now my questions**: To answer my initial problem, **how to calculate the distance from the medial axis to the 2 boundaries at equidistant n points on the medial axis?**.

[image: N points on medial axis]

Also is there any better way of answering my initial question?

I am using Python 3.9

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can compute the distance transform of the medial axis.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't find a way to do it. If you know, please let me know

Comment: But you could compute the distance transform of the original shape !

Comment: @YvesDaoust No. The previous distance function's peaks are including the branching.

Comment: You don't get it, you are able to compute a distance map, right ?

Comment: I can't compute the distance map using the medial axis I have, if you know a way, please suggest.

Comment: The same way that you used.

Comment: But there is unwanted branching. As you can see in the above image. If I take the point where branching happens, the distance from there to left and the right boundary is not equal. So if I double the distance at that point, it is not accurately giving me the thickness

Comment: I said distance from the medial axis, didn't I ?